# Yii: CDbCriteria doesn't replace placeholder with provided value

Tags: php, sql, yii

I have the following code:

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->condition = ' action_id 
IN(SELECT action_id FROM action_type WHERE action_name = \'EnableGame\') ';
$criteria->compare('task_id','= '.$taskData->task_id, false, 'AND');
$criteria->compare('value', '= '.$gameData->game_id, false, 'AND');
$enablingActions = TaskActions::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

In `compare` method `task_id` and `value` are not compared against the provided values but like are not to passed in the function. Here is how Yii translates to SQL query the code above:

```
Querying SQL: SELECT * FROM "task_actions" "t" 
WHERE 
  (( 
    action_id IN(SELECT action_id FROM action_type WHERE action_name = 'EnableGame'
  ) ) 
AND (task_id=:ycp0)) 
AND (value=:ycp1)
```

Why I see placeholders `:ycp0` and `ycp1` instead the values I set? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the placeholders are replaced with the actual values by the database engine and even Yii itself does not see the "final" form of the query at all.

However, there is an option that enables logging of the parameter values side-by-side with the query: set the connection's [`enableParamLogging`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbConnection#enableParamLogging-detail) attribute to `true` and the values will be logged as part of the same message (it continues "Bound with ...").

Comment: Thank you @Jon . Let me ask you one more think. I want to replace `$criteria->compare('task_id','= '.$taskData->task_id, false, 'AND');` with something like `$criteria->compare('task_id',':task_id', false, 'AND'); $criteria->params=array(':task_id', $taskData->task_id);` It doesn't work in my case as you guess. The log says: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT * FROM "task_actions" "t" WHERE (( action_id IN(SELECT action_id FROM action_type WHERE action_name = 'EnableGame') ) AND (task_id=:ycp0)) AND (value=:ycp1).